# How can I update rekeyed certificates on stunnel?

Tags: ssl, haproxy, stunnel

I have configured stunnel using GoDaddy certificate and it was working fine. Due to some circumstances, I need to rekey the certificate and update the pem file on the load balancer. Upon updating the pem file, it turned out that the certificate status is revoked. I've checked this to GoDaddy and they said that there's nothing wrong with the certificate.

I also used some tools to verify the installed certificate and noticed that the original certificate is still recognized. Is there any caching mechanism on stunnel or in the load balancer which keeps the original data? Are there any additional steps on updating the certificates on stunnel?

I used this guideline for the stunnel setup: http://help.cloud66.com/how-to/ssl-termination-on-load-balancers.html

Comment: The issue has been resolved already. Just noticed something on stunnel behavior (not sure if this is the normal thing for this). When you reload the updated config file (stunnel /etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf), the previous process was not killed. It is required to kill all the processes first before starting the service again.